# Left align a rotated text inside a flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a card like structure in a webpage. Each card is a graph. I need to display the y axis label for each graph for any aspect ratio of cards.
HTML

```
<div class="grid">
     <div class="chart">
          <h2>Test 1</h2>      
          <div class="graphAxisY">test y lable</div>
          <Graph class="graph">(This is the graph)</Graph>
          <div>test x lable</div>
     </div>
     <div class="chart">
          <h2>Test 2</h2>      
          <div class="graphAxisY">test y lable</div>
          <Graph class="graph">(This is the graph)</Graph>
          <div>test x lable</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.graphAxisY{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(-22%, 25%);  
  background-color: transparent; 
  z-index: 100; 
}
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,33%);
}
.chart{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-right: 0.8vw;
}
```

Result is fine when the aspect ratio of graphs is 4
[image: Aspect ratio 4]

Results is not fine when aspect ratio of a graph is 1
[image: Aspect ratio 1]

Notice the Y label text is not centered in vertical axis. **How can I put the Y axis label for a flex box with a variable aspect ratio?**

Answer (score 1):

Could you change the `chart` display actually to "flow-root" instead, like so?:

```css
.graphAxisY {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(-33%, 0%);
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 100;
}

.graphAxisX {
  text-align: center;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 33%);
}

.chart {
  display: flow-root;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-right: 0.8vw;
}

.graph {
  padding: 0% 15% 25% 15%;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="chart">
    <h2>Test 1</h2>
    <div class="graphAxisY">test y label</div>
    <Graph class="graph">(This is the graph)</Graph>
    <div class="graphAxisX">test x label</div>
  </div>
  <div class="chart">
    <h2>Test 2</h2>
    <div class="graphAxisY">test y label</div>
    <Graph class="graph">(This is the graph)</Graph>
    <div class="graphAxisX">test x label</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: example of snippet]

Comment: Hi @John , your answer did not work. Y label was still not centered vertically. And also graphs overlapped

Comment: @AkilaUyanwatta If you could provide the full, or a minimally reproducible full, example of the code as an HTML/CSS/javascript snippet using the SO feature like I did - that would make it significantly more likely to ensure a provided answer correctly addresses your unique context/problem/situation !  (b/c it worked when I tested it with the code you provided! I added a screenshot to answer. I understand how it may not work for your actual graphs though...although I thought it would if implemented in the same html tag hierarchy structure)